# view function not work properly on code igniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, view

hi i try to make basic view edit and delete on codeigniter

im using table on customers/index.php to show all the customers data from db and it works, but when i try to open view function to view spesific customer with $id as a parameter only 1st data that showed, the 2rd, 3rd and so on show 404.

this ss of my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnCod.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpUBa.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOcbT.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75QNE.jpg

here ss of my db structure

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ohbu.jpg

customers/index.php

```
<h2 align="center"><?= $title ?></br></h2>
<table table table-hover width="100%" border="1">
<thead>
<tr class="table-danger">   
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Company</th>
    <th scope="col">Company Address</th>
    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>
    <th scope="col">Action</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
<?php foreach($customers as $row): ?>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-light">   
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['company']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td align="justify">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('/customers/view/'.$row['id']); ?>">Edit/Delete</a>
    </p>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<p align="center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/customers/insert');?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Insert</button></a></p>
```

controller/Customers.php

```
    class Customers extends CI_Controller{
        public function index(){
            $data['title'] = 'Customers';

            $data['customers'] = $this->Cust_model->get_customers();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('customers/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

        public function view($id = NULL){


            $data['customer'] = $this->Cust_model->get_customers($id);

            if(empty($data['customer'])){
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = 'View Customer';

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('customers/view', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function insert(){
            $data['title'] = 'Add New Customer';

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('company','Company', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address','Address', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Phone', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('customers/insert', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            } else {
                $this->Cust_model->insert_customer();
                redirect('customers');

            }
        }

        public function delete($id){
            $this->Cust_model->delete_cust($id);
            redirect('customers');
        }
public function edit($id = NULL){

            $data['customer'] = $this->Cust_model->get_customers($id);

            if($id == NULL){
                $id = $this->uri-segment(4);
            }

            $data['title'] = 'Edit Customer';

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('customers/edit', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
```

models/Cust_model.php

```
<?php
    class Cust_model extends CI_Model{
        public function _construc(){
            $this->load->database();

        }

        public function get_customers($name = FALSE){
            if($name === FALSE){
                $query = $this->db->get('cust_table');
                return $query->result_array();
            }
            $query = $this->db->get_where('cust_table', array('name', $name));
            return $query->row_array();
        }

        public function insert_customer(){

            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'company' => $this->input->post('company'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),

            );

            return $this->db->insert('cust_table', $data);
        }

        public function delete_cust($id){
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->delete('cust_table');
            return true;
        }

        public function edit($id, $data){
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $result = $this->db->update('cust_table', $data);

            if($result){
                return $id;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

customers/view.php

```
<h2 align="center"><?= $title ?></br></h2>
<table table table-hover width="100%" border="1">
<thead>
<tr class="table-danger">   
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Company</th>
    <th scope="col">Company Address</th>
    <th scope="col">Phone</th>
    <th scope="col">Email</th>

</tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-light">   
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $customer['id']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $customer['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['company']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $customer['email']; ?></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p align="center"><br><a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('/customers/edit/'.$customer['id']); ?>">Edit</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo site_url('/customers/delete/'.$customer['id']); ?>">Delete</a>
```

input works fine, and delete works fine too when i try to put the button delete on index.php it got deleted the right id on the table

pls help me, thank you

Comment: can you explain what you mean by this "only 1st data that showed, the 2rd, 3rd and so on show 404."? I don't see anything wrong with your method, so are you sure the names exist?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, when you look at the index.php that i made.

Comment: i think i figured it out. please see if it works.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, when you look at the index.php that i made. i create table with looping data, ive input 3 data to db with id 1, 2 and 3. at the action colom i added edit or delete buttot that bring me to customers/view, all the name i added show on index.php, but when i clicked on edit on action coloum on 1st data that showed that bring me to  customers/view.php with all data from value $customer['name'] showed, but when i clicked on other data on index.php like with id 2 or 3 ith show 404

Comment: isn't that then because you are `array('name', $name)` in query `get_customers` so you expect name not id? should be: `<?php echo site_url('/customers/view/'.$row['name']); ?>`

Comment: im sorry, ive change $name into $id on my model cos if im using name i it contain (space), so only the 1st data that showed on view.the otherr data from index not show on view

Comment: Updated my code again, so you should search where column is Id not name then

Comment: updated the question with some pics

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the id you need to use the id column in the where function `get_customers()` not the name. Further it appears as though the array was not properly declared should be `array('id' => $id)` instead of `array('id', $id)`.

I've updated the function for clarity changing the `$name` variable to `$id`.

```
    public function get_customers($id = null){
        if(is_null($id)){
            $query = $this->db->get('cust_table');
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('cust_table', array('id' => $id));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

---

I also suggest to use either flash messages and redirecting user to the index function to say the user doesn't exist if the return result of `get_customers()` is empty or to use `show_error('user does not exist', 400)` as a 404  might be confusing to some people.

Comment: i got error Message: Undefined index: id. for all the data id, name, company, address, phone, email

Comment: Updated please fix the function and the link (1st method)

Comment: Updated again as per your new comment

Comment: wait a sec, ill try it out. and sorry btw im noob hehehe

Comment: ive changed it, but it make the 1st data show 404 too

Comment: wait ill upload my code from localhost to my testing server

Comment: I'm going to bed now. But maybe just try it with the first modification and not the second to rule that out. Otherwise you need to see what column you want to do the where from and if the id is the right column and if that item you are trying to find actually exists.

Comment: Also post an image of the table structure and what the table data looks like on imgur and paste links into your question as an edit.

Comment: i was tired last night and the error alluded me. the error was so simple even i missed in my original passes `array('name', $id')` should be `array('id' => $name)` please use updated function and your problems should go away.